# How to use different y values along x axis with contour(f)

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I'm trying to plot a meridional wind field at a lat/pressure grid with hybrid sigma pressure coordinates in Matplotlib. I can make this work to set one y vector (called level) including pressure values for all x coordinates:

[image]

```py
lat_plot = np.linspace(-90, -60, 36)
level = np.linspace(0, 1000, 26)[::-1]
v = np.random.rand(len(lat_plot), len(level))
topo_zm = np.random.uniform(0, 3000, len(lat_plot))

levels = [-1, -0.875, -0.75, -0.625, -0.5, -0.375, -0.25, -0.125, 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1]
ticks = [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize = [15,7.5])
ax = fig.add_subplot()
im1 = ax.contour(lat_plot, level, v, levels = levels, colors = "black", linewidths = 0.5, linestyles = "solid")
im2 = ax.contourf(lat_plot, level, v, levels = levels, cmap = "coolwarm", extend = "both")
ax.set_xlim(-90, -60)
ax.set_xlabel("latitude [°]")
ax.set_xticklabels([-90, -80, -70, -60])
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_ylim(v.lev[0], 300)
ax.set_ylabel("pressure [hPa]")
ax.set_yticks([900, 700, 500, 300])
ax.set_title("4PIC", fontsize = 10)

ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.plot(lat_plot, topo_zm, color = "Black")
ax1.fill_between(lat_plot, topo_zm, color = "Black", alpha = 0.3)
ax1.set_ylim(0,10000)
ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

fig.suptitle("Zonal-mean meriodional summer (DJ) wind averaged around West- (180°-360°E) and East-Antarctica (0°-180°E)", x = 0.52, y = 0.94)
plt.show()
```

However, the idea of this hybrid sigma coordinate system is that every x has a different y vector belonging to it (i.e., the length of these vectors is the same, but their values are different). `lat_plot` should then be a 36x1 array, `level` a 36x26 array (with a different 1x26 vector for every value of lat_plot) and `v` should then be a 36x26 array. `level` should then be replaced by `level_sigma`, which is something like:

```
level_sigma = np.zeros_like(v)
for i in range(len(level)):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, len(level_sigma))[::-1]
    order = a.argsort()
    level_sigma[:,i] = a[order]
```

How do I make this work? Maybe I'm thinking to difficult already, so my essential question is: how do I recreate the plot above, such that the contours do not overlap the topography (i.e, the contours start from the topography upwards)? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide sample data for `lat_plot`, `level` and `v` please ?

Comment: Thanks @DennVer, `lat_plot1` and `topo_zm` are not provided as well. Please can you update the question with a MWE (code + data) and I'll be happy to help you.